# Обработка вариативного массива с++

Tags: c++

Подскажите плз как правильно передать вариативный массив в процедуру печати, если приходит `args=(char const (&)[32]`)

```
void printff(char const c[])
{
    std::printf("%s", c);
}


template <typename... Args>
void print(Args&&... args) noexcept
{
    printff(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://github.com/eteran/cxx11_printf/blob/master/Printf.h#L796

Comment: `char c[]` -> `const char c[]`. Других проблем не вижу.